# Finding the first n largest elements in an array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory

I have got an array containing unique elements. I need to find out the first n largest elements in the array in the least complexity possible. The solution that I could think of so far has a complexity of O(n^2).

```
    int A[]={1,2,3,8,7,5,3,4,6};
    int max=0;
    int i,j;
    int B[4]={0,0,0,0,};//where n=4;
     for(i=0;i<A.length();i++)
       {
         if(A[i]>max)
          max=A[i];
       }
     B[0]=max;
     for(i=1;i<n;i++){
       max=0;
       for(j=0;j<A.length();j++){
         if(A[j]>max&&A[j]<B[i-1])
            max=A[j];
       }
        B[i]=max;
     }
```

Please, if anyone can come up with a better solution which involves less complexity, I will be highly grateful. And I don't intend to change the original array!!

Comment: `sort` the array using your favorite `O(n log n)` algorithm and select the N biggest elements?

Comment: what are "the first n largest elements"? The `n` largest? or the first `n`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Comment: Your complexity is not O(n^2).. it's O(n*k) k being the number of largest elements you want. it's only O(n^2) if n = k. So, if k is small enough your algorithm is not that bad..

Comment: go to profile, select one of questions and then need to checkmark one of answers that best answers your question. do that with all of your questions.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Find the kth biggest element, using [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

Next, iterate the array and find all elements which are larger/equal it.

**complexity:** O(n) for selection and O(n) for iterating, so the total is also O(n)

Comment: But if the array size is `n` and you also need to find the `n` largest elements, then this will run `n` times, each is O(n), so in total it will be O(n^2)... It would be better to sort it.

Comment: @kuhaku No. You find the `n`th largest element in `O(n)`, let it be `x`, and then in a single more iteration find all elements with index `i` such that `arr[i] >= x`. This is also done in `O(n)`, and it yields total of `O(n + n) = O(n)`.

Comment: How in a single iteration do you find all the others? Isn't it a loop from 1 to n where in each iteration you do `selection(n-i)`?

Comment: @kuhaku You don't you found one element using selection, and you know its value. You then only iterate to find all elements bigger than it, no selection is needed (Note that the output is not sorted, you get elements in undefined order, which are the biggest elements, but their internal order is undefined)

Comment: Sorry to dig up this question, but wouldn't it be faster to do just 1 pass through the array with a subset of k maximums? For each new value you compare with the min of the subset, if it's bigger you store it and search the new subset min, if it's not you move on. If I'm right that would be a best case of `k*k+(n-k)` iterations and a worst case of `k*n`iterations

Comment: @FlorentEcochard I am not sure I understand your approach, but `k*k + (n-k) = (k-1)*k + k + n-k = (k-1)*k + n`, and this is `O(k^2 + n)`, which is worse than `O(n)` especially when `k->n`, where you then get `O(n^2)` time, compared to `O(n)` using selection.

Comment: Well my approach is to go through the array only once, and keep a subset of `k` maximums, as well as the minimum value of this subset (let's call it `m`). For each new sample of the array, you compare it with `m` and if it's bigger you replace it. You now have to find the new `m` of your subset.

If we set `k=10` and `n=256`, that gives us a best case of `(k-1)*k + n = 346` and a worst of `k*n = 2560` iterations.
I'm not familiar with QuickSelect but wikipedia says it has a WC of `O(n^2)`, and you also have to go through the whole array a second time in your method which adds 256 iterations

Comment: @FlorentEcochard (1) The worst case of quickselect is highly unlikely, and the average case is O(n) for it. (2) If you are afraid of it, you can use median of medians technique to get O(n) worst case performance. (3) I think you might be referring to a naive variant of the heap solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10751982/572670)

Answer (score 13):

The usual trick to select the *n* largest elements is to maintain a min-priority queue.

- Unconditionnally insert into the queue the *n* first elements
- For each remaining element x, insert x if it is greater than the least element of the queue (O(log n) operation), and remove the least element (O(log n)).
- When done, the priority queue contains *n* elements, which are the *n* largest elements of the original array.

Total complexity: O(N log n) where N is the total number of elements in the array.

I leave to you as an exercise the implementation details (first step is to learn about priority queues, and implement one).

Comment: Note that although this is slower than @amit's QuickSelect based solution, it's an online algorithm applicable to an unbounded input stream

Comment: @YiboYang Yes, and even in the bounded case, everything will ultimately depends on whether log n can be considered small or not.

Comment: Use this solution if you need the results sorted. Otherwise use Amit's solution.

Comment: @BarryFruitman : also use my version if you are only allowed one pass through the data, or if it does not fit in memory.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in O(n) if your elements are integers (or any integral type) within a range, i to k inclusive with k >= i.  With this constraint, you can apply "bucket sort" to this.

The idea is quite simple. Allocate k - i + 1 buckets. Now, iterate through your collection and increment the bucket for that integer.  Then, at the end, you can "recreate" the sorted list by creating as many integers that were found (i.e. the bucket number).

For example,

```
int collection[] = { 10, 4, 7, 1, 9, 0, 12 }; // maximum value to expect is 12, minimum is 0
int buckets[ 13 ] = { 0 };

for( int i = 0; i < 13; i++ )
{
      int n = collection[ i ];
      buckets[ n ]++;
}


// the first n largest elements (n = 4)

for( int j = 12; j >= 12 - 4; j-- )
{
      int n = buckets[ j ];

      while( n > 0 )
      {
           printf( "%d ", j );
           n--;
      }
}
printf( "\n" );
```

Comment: please give answer this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68721689/how-to-find-print-n-largest-element-of-array

Answer (score 1):

Use a modified version of Quick Sort. You do not need to actually sort the whole array. You only need to partition N elements larger than the pivot value. For more information, please read Introduction to Algorithms.

Comment: I want to do it without using any sorting algorithms!!

Comment: Is this a homework question? That seems like a strangely specific requirement.

Comment: @Poulami: Don't you think that's a detail worth mentioning in the question?

Comment: Aside from @Poulami's request, I don't think this would actually work - the choice of the pivot value for quicksort is often random. To make a non-random guess, you would need some information about the order or size of elements in advance, which you don't have in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Priority Queue using Heap (maxHeap) to solve this. Perform heap n times to get the first n largest elements. Each Heap operation takes O(log N) time, so N heap operations would result in O(N log N) time.

Comment: Something wrong with the complexity analysis here (specifically: incorrectly using the same variable N for size of input and size of output)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe on this but you could also create a heap out of it in O(n). And then just remove the root k number of times and heapify the heap for k largest numbers.
In this way for each largest numbers it will cost you log(n).

```
public class HeapSort1{                                                          
    public static void main(String args[]){                                  
            int[] array={5,75,1,5,4,1,2,4,8,4,2,15,4,2,1,5,779,9,1};         
            int heapsize=array.length-1;                                     
            for(int i=heapsize/2;i>=0;i--){                                  
                    maxHeapify(array,i,heapsize);                            
            }                                                                
            for(int i=heapsize;i>0;i--){                                     
                    array[i]=array[0]+array[i];                              
                    array[0]=array[i]-array[0];                              
                    array[i]=array[i]-array[0];                              
                    maxHeapify(array,0,--heapsize);                          
            }                                                                
            printArray(array);                                               
    }                                                                        
    public static void maxHeapify(int[] array,int i,int heapsize){           
            int largest=i;                                                   
            int left=2*i+1;                                                  
            int right=2*i+2;                                                 
            if(left<=heapsize && array[left]>array[i]){                      
                    largest=left;                                            
            }                                                                
            if(right<=heapsize && array[right]>array[largest]){              
                    largest=right;                                           
            }                                                                
            if(largest!=i){                                                  
                    array[i]=array[largest]+array[i];                        
                    array[largest]=array[i]-array[largest];                  
                    array[i]=array[i]-array[largest];                        
                    maxHeapify(array,largest,heapsize);                      
            }                                                                
    }                                                                        
    public static void printArray(int[] array){                              
            System.out.print("\n [");                                        
            for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){                                 
                    System.out.print(array[i]+" ");                          
            }                                                                
            System.out.print("] \n");                                        
    }  
    public static int getMax(){
            int max=array[0];
            array[0]=array[heapsize];
            maxHeapify(array,0,--heapsize);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this as per @Alexandre C.

This gets the top 10 items of a unbounded input. It breaks after it processed 20 items from the input.

```
import random
import time
top_10_items = []
cnt = 1
while True:
    rand = random.randint(1,100)
    print(rand)

    time.sleep(1)
    if len(top_10_items) !=10:
        top_10_items.append(rand)
    else:
        m = min(top_10_items)
        if rand > m:
            top_10_items.append(rand)
            top_10_items.remove(m)

    print(top_10_items)

    cnt+=1
    if cnt==20:
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    //First we sort the array in descending order and after the array 
//is sorted, we print the number of largest elements we want

  import java.util.Scanner;
class bubble_sort{
    
    static void buuble_sort(int[] array,int n){

        int temp=0;
//I have sorted this array using bubble sorting technique, in case you don't know, you must know, it's effective, easy and fast.

        for (int i=0; i<n;++i){
            for (int j=0;j<n-1;j++){
                if (array[j]<array[j+1]){
                     temp=array[j];
                    array[j]=array[j+1];
                    array[j+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
//this method print the number of 'n' largest we want.
    static void print_sort(int array[],int num){
        for (int i=0;i<num;++i){
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
         Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);   
    int[] array={12, 34, 56, 32, 45, 22,3, 18};
    int n=array.length;
     System.out.println("the elements of the array are as follows:-");
     for (int i=0; i<array.length;++i){
        System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
     }
    buuble_sort(array,n);
    System.out.print("\nEnter the number of largest elements you want from the above array : ");
//give the integer input as 'n' number of largest elements.
    int num=obj.nextInt();
    print_sort(array,num);
        

}
}
```

Comment: You are answering to a +10 years accepted C question with an uncommented and unformatted code in Java, why?

Answer (score -5):

```
//finding the bigest number in the array//

double big = x[0];
for(t=0;t<x[t];t++)
{
    if(x[t]>big)
    {
        big=x[t];
    }
}
printf("\nThe bigest number is    %0.2lf  \n",big);
```