# Hierachial Tree buiding from flat collection

Tags: c#, algorithm, hierarchical-data

I need to build a tree from hierarchical flat collection separated by dots (.) like namespaces in C# for example. Here are some entry values as a collection (ordered):

```
A0.A0.A0
A1
A1.A2
A2.A3.A3.A2
A3.A2
A3.A4.A5.A3
A3.A4.A5.A4
B0.B1.B0
B1.B2
B1.B2.B3
B1.B2.B4
```

This collection looks like namespaces in C#. So let's assume they are namespaces (as you can understand A.A.A.A namespace is really legal).

What I need?

I need a parent-child tree from this collection like this (note, we save some space concatenating some names in one):

```
A0.A0.A0
A1
   A2
A2.A3.A3.A2
A3
   A2
   A4.A5        
      A3
      A4
B0.B1.B0
B1.B2
     B3
     B4
```

In this case we will have only 6 root objects.

Here is our interface for our algorithm:

```
    public interface IParentChild
    {
        IEnumerable<IParentChild> Children { get; set; }
        string FullName { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: It seems your tree is not correct. A3 and A4 should be move to the right one step (from under A5)

Comment: Does the `IParentChild` interface model the result of running the algorithm? what is the difference between `FullName` and `Name`?

Comment: What did you try to do so far?

Comment: do you want to generate text file ? or you want to parse from text file into collection?

Comment: A2 on the 6th line should be after A3 at the 5th line I guess?

Comment: So many question. Imagine we have a list of namespaces in the project. And instead of flat view of them I wanna do simply a hierarchal view. But a little bit compressed. Some nodes could be joined together to have not so deep level. For example B1.B2 in the last row could be united. 

Also, may be I have some formatting errors. But the idea I hope is understandable.

Comment: Andrey is asking a question very common here at SO. Ever hovered over the vote down button? The tooltip is very enlightening.

Comment: venerik, no. It's not common. And yes I know how to search and I am asking not about how to use google and other search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a Trie data structure as given in this answer [Parsing one terabyte of text and efficiently counting the number of occurrences of each word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190326/parsing-one-terabyte-of-text-and-efficiently-counting-the-number-of-occurrences)
2. Modify the Trie generation code in #1 to store namespaces
3. Walk the Trie and output the contents to the console.

If you need more detail, comment on this and I can quickly code it.

Comment: You could be a little briefer. Writing: 'Simply do it' :)
Actually I already have done it alone. But I like your comment. It's really genius and very helpful for every stackoverflow user. I approve it as a working solution.