# stackalloc (C# Reference)

Tags: c#, memory, information-retrieval, text-parsing

i'm trying to parse 130,000 document , and i'm trying to do that as fast as i can.

this function is for removing the delimiter char in Document.

```
public static unsafe string StripRestAndNewlines(string s)
{
    int len = s.Length;
    char* newChars = stackalloc char[len];
    char* currentChar = newChars;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        char c = s[i];
        switch (c)
        {
            case ',':
            case '.':
            case ':':
            case ';':
            case '-':
            case '>':
            case '<':
            case '/':
            case '\\':
            case '?':
            case '"':
            case '*':
            case '&':
            case '_':
            case '+':
            case '@':
            case '[':
            case ']':
            case '!':
            case '=':
            case '%':
            case '#':
                continue;
            default:
                *currentChar++ = c;
                break;
        }
    }
  return new string(newChars, 0, (int)(currentChar - newChars));            
}
```

but after 2 min of running the program stop and i'm getting

> system.StackOverflowException

is there any delete[] of free for the allocate?

thanks!

Comment: *Why* are you trying to use stack allocation for this? Presumably your document is very large... trying to allocate the whole memory required for the string on the stack seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: i'm trying to use as less memory as possible, also is the most fast way that i find. That why i'm looking for a way to free/delete the allocate.

Comment: if you are trying to remove chars I am wondering you wouldn't write your own little extension method to replace particular chars 
`public static string ReplaceCharsAt(this string input, int index, char newChar)`

Comment: generally using less memory is opposite of going as fast as possible.

Comment: Well you're still creating a new string at the end of it - so you could just clone the origin string, and then modify a pinned version of that.

Comment: I think this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190326/parsing-one-terabyte-of-text-and-efficiently-counting-the-number-of-occurrences) on the Trie data structure may help you.

Answer (score 3):

> is there any delete[] of free for the allocate?

Yes, doing nothing. Since its stack-allocated it will be immediately deleted as soon as the method returns (your mentioning `delete[]` suggests you are drawing analogy to C++, but note that in C++ you don't `delete[]` stack-allocated variables).

You won't get that far though, because you are stack-allocating too much.

`stackalloc` is of very limited use. It tends to be slower than just using heap memory unless you are using it as an alternative to `fixed` or in a few situations where different threads are allow allocating large arrays at the same time. It's only appropriate for use arrays smaller than a few kilobytes at the outside.

You're going to be better off using a heap array. You may or may not be better off using pointers and `fixed`.

You'd be much, much better off parsing the document(s) in chunks. If at all possible load them in from streams only in moderate-sized segments of 4kiB or 8kiB and process each such chunk as it comes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no delete method I think. It's a stack, you can add something on top, and remove things from top. You cannot remove things from middle of stack. Allocated memory is automatically freed when method returns.
I think stackoverflow occurs when incoming string is very long. Use heap memory to this task. Just create a new array.

Comment: still heap is getting me slower but good to know that i cant thanks.

Comment: then maybe create a static array? you will avoid instance creation every method call. If incoming string will be too big, you will resize that array.