# How to process text from gutenberg project?

Tags: c#, nlp, project-gutenberg

I'm using C#.I was given a task which is that I need to process txt files of books from project gutenberg here is an excerpt from that task

> Each file you should parse to:
> Sentences;
> Words;
> Punctuation.
> For each file you should generate a new file. The name of that file is the
> name of the book. In each of those file you should have:
> Longest sentence by number of characters;
> Shortest sentence by numbers of words;
> Longest word;
> Most common letter;
> Words sorted by the number of uses in descending order;"
> How do I omit tables of contents, chapter titles, and other non-sentence elements ? It uses stanford nlp to separate sentences into words

I installed stanford nlp, except that it often treats tables of contents , chapter titles and other phrases that are not actual sentences as sentences.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12396706