# Save top N results to fixed array - sequentially

Tags: java, arrays

I have a huge list of numbers and I'm doing some calculations over each record, e.g:

```
123 456 789 213 546 789 78 156 489 952 456 789 ......
```

and after proccessing the list I'm getting the results **sequentially** (they are not stored in any structure), e.g.

```
0.156 0.895 0.12 0.145 0.146 0.222 0.123 0.489 ........
```

Is there some practice, how to save for example top 5 results to **fixed** array?

1st step:

```
[0.156]
```

2nd step:

```
[0.895 0.156]
```

5th step:

```
[0.895 0.156 0.146 0.145 0.12]
```

nth step:

```
[0.895 0.489 0.222 0.156 0.146]
```

It should have complexity O(n), because there is no sorting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Top Four Maximum value from Java Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122526/getting-top-four-maximum-value-from-java-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `LinkedList` and only insert in the first 5 elements, I think this would work.

```
public List<Double> getTop(List<Double> inputs) {
    List<Double> top = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Double input : inputs) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 5 && i < top.size() && input < top.get(i))
            i++;
        if (i < 5)
            top.add(i, input);
    }
    return top.subList(0, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is pretty easy you have a 5 element array say

[88, 77, 66, 55, 44]

for each **new number** search through the array and insert in the **approriate possition**
if there is one (a basic for / while loop can be used).

i.e. if you get 60 the array would become

[88, 77, 66, 60, 55]

There are issues like at the start before you get 5 element. Since this is an exercise I will leave you to write the code

Answer (score 0):

In case of only 5 elements, iterating over the array and saving max 5 elements is not so hard.

You can take a look at [this](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/selecting-top-k-items-from-a-list-efficiently-in-java-groovy/), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084495/find-top-n-elements-in-an-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784323/1651233) for a more comprehensive answers.