# Extract first k elements from a Set efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm

**Problem**

I'm writing a simple Java program in which I have a `TreeSet` which contains *Comparable* elements (it's a class that I've written myself). In a specific moment I need to take **only** the first *k* elements from it.

**What I've done**

Currently I've found two different solution for my problem:

1. Using a simple method written by me; It copies the first *k* elements from the initial `TreeSet`;
2. Use **Google Guava** [greatestOf](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#greatestOf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29) method.

For the second option you need to call the method in this way:
`Ordering.natural().greatestOf(mySet, 80))`

But I think that it's useless to use this kind of invocation because the elements are already sorted. Am I wrong?

**Question**

I want to ask here which is a correct and, at the same time, efficient method to obtain a `Collection` derived class which contains the first *k* elements of a `TreeSet`?

**Additional information**

Java version: >= 7

Comment: Do you wish the new collection to change if the original `Set` changes? If so you could wrap the `Set` in another object - a very efficient mechanism.

Comment: The generated `Set` is never modified.

Comment: I don't want to close yet, but it seems like partially dupe of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10751953/572670), at least in the algorithmic part of it.

Comment: "...the elements are already sorted..."  The elements of a java.util.SortedSet are sorted.  The elements of a java.util.Set have no defined ordering.  (That is to say, an implementation of Set is allowed to iterate over its elements in any order.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Guava's `Iterables#limit`:

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.limit(yourSet, 7))
```

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#limit(java.lang.Iterable, int)

Comment: I'm trying your solution, it seems the best one.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a `TreeSet<YourComparableClass>` collection, it seems to be the solution you are looking for.

A TreeSet can return you an iterator, and you can simply iterates K times, by storing the objects the iterator returns you: the elements will be returned you in order.

Moreover a TreeSet keep your elements always sorted: at any time, when you add or remove elements, they are inserted and removed so that the structure remains ordered.

Here a possible example:

```
public static ArrayList<YourComparableClass> getFirstK(TreeSet<YourComparableClass> set, int k) {
    Iterator<YourComparableClass> iterator = set.iterator();
    ArrayList<YourComparableClass> result = new ArrayList<>(k); //to store first K items
    for (int i=0;i<k;i++) result.add(iterator.next()); //iterator returns items in order
    //you should also check iterator.hasNext(); if you are not sure to have always a K<set.size()
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This answer could be associated with my first solution. Is it right?

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia yes, now that you've edited your question is more clear that you already had in mind a solution of this kind

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I think that it's useless to write a method again if there is something really good available :)

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia actually the TreeSet is the only collections that fir your requirements, but it does not provide a method like the one you described, so if you want to use a TreeSet this is the easier way to do.. if you want to use Guava then it's another story ;)

Comment: You can more elegantly do it in a single statement: `return (ArrayList<YourComparableClass>) set.stream().limit(k).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

The [`descendingIterator()` method of `java.util.TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#descendingIterator%28%29) yields elements from greatest to least, so you can just step it however many times, inserting the elements into a collection. The running time is O(log n + k) where k is the number of elements returned, which is surely fast enough.

If you're using a `HashSet`, on the other hand, then the elements in fact are *not* sorted, so you need to use the linear-time selection method that you indicated.