# C# - Taking top 10 values and multiplying them

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary

I am currently working on a bayesian spam filter, made a filter using an algorithm, but it wil not work for long emails, there are just too much values to multiply and it excedes the range of `double`. I thought about making it so that I only take 10 or 20 most important (highest values for both spam and ham) and multiply only them. I thought about making another `Dictionary` inside and then multiply values out of it.

This is how it looks right now:

```
if (countsWordOccurenceSpam.ContainsKey(word.Key) && (!countsWordOccurenceOk.ContainsKey(word.Key)))
{
    int spamValue = 0;
    countsWordOccurenceSpam.TryGetValue(word.Key, out spamValue);
    totals = spamValue ;

    fprob_spam = ((double)spamValue) / ile_spam;

        sum_spam = (((weight * probability) + (totals * fprob_spam)) / (totals + weight));
        sum_ok = ((weight * probability) / (totals + weight));

        sum_spam = Math.Pow(sum_spam, word.Value);
        sum_ok = Math.Pow(sum_ok, word.Value);

        wp_spam_1 = wp_spam_1 * sum_spam;
        last_o_1 = last_o_1 * sum_ok;                       
}
```

This is one part of algorithm, now I am thinking about putting all the values from sum_spam to one `Dictionary`, and all the values from `sum_ok` to another and take using `.Take(10)` to select 10 highest values and multiply all of them.

Does it seem right? I am really thinking it would be very inefficient, Is there any way to do it?

Comment: [getting top k of a list can be done pretty efficiently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10751953/572670). However, I doubt that is really a good solution for spam filtering. Why don't you use standard Machine Learning algorithms for it?

Comment: I think I am using a standard one? I am implementing one from a book I've bought. It is naive bayesian, checks each word probability and then multiply all of that probabilities. If the total spam probability is higher I am putting the mail into spam.