# How to select top N values and sum them in mathematical optimization

Tags: math, machine-learning, mathematical-optimization

I have an array of values (probabilities) as below,

```
  a = [0, 0.1, 0.9, 0.2, 0, 0.8, 0.7, 0]
```

To select the maximum value from this array I can use the generalized mean equation. But what should I do if I want to select say top N values and sum them?

e.g. summing top 2 values will give me 0.9 + 0.8 = 1.7

**** But I dont need an implementation/algorithm for it. I need a mathematical equation (e.g. generalized mean for selecting the max value), so that I want to optimize a function which includes this selection.

Comment: How large can `a` get? If it's not too big, a simple sort and slice should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the first n largest elements in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272534/finding-the-first-n-largest-elements-in-an-array)

Comment: Is the individual values important, or just the sum?

Answer (score 0):

Effective way to get top K values is using of some K-select algorithm.
For example, fast and reliable one is [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) (based on the same partition procedure as QuickSort), which has average complexity O(N).

`generalized mean` with regard to maximum seems pure mathematical conception, doesn't it?
So I doubt that sum of **infinite** powers is applicable in real life (programming).