# Find the K closest points to the origin (0, 0)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, return

The problem is, given a list of coordinates, determine the number of k coordinates that are closest to the origin.

I have been able to determine the distance between the points and origin, however when filtering for the closest k points, I am lost. I decided to place this logic in a the second for loop, sort the array of distance from closest to furthest, and push the values that are less than K.

```js
function kClosest(points, k) {
    let length = [];
    let arr = [];
    let result = [];
    let a = 0;
    let b = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        a = points[i][0]; //x coord
        b = points[i][1]; //y coord (y will always be second number or '1')
        length.push(parseFloat(calcHypotenuse(a, b).toFixed(4)))
        arr.push([points[i], length[i]])
    }

    function calcHypotenuse(a, b) {
        return (Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b)));
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        arr = arr.sort();
        result.push(arr[i][0])
    }
    return result;
}



console.log(kClosest([
    [-5, 4],
    [-6, -5],
    [4, 6]
], K = 2))
```

Expected output: [-5, 4], [4, 6] // I had [-5, 4], [-6, -5]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the first n largest elements in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272534/finding-the-first-n-largest-elements-in-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using a custom sort for this - you can pass `Array.sort()` a comparison function, like this:

```js
function kClosest(points, k) {

    //sorts the array in place
    points.sort((point1, point2) => {
        const distanceFromOrigin1 = getDistanceFromOrigin(point1);
        const distanceFromOrigin2 = getDistanceFromOrigin(point2);

        //sort by distance from origin, lowest first
        return distanceFromOrigin1 - distanceFromOrigin2;
    });

    //returns first k elements
    return points.slice(0, k);
}

function getDistanceFromOrigin(point) {
    const [x, y] = point; //array destructuring
    return (x*x) + (y*y);
}

console.log(kClosest([
    [-5, 4],
    [-6, -5],
    [4, 6]
], 2))
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort for more details on custom sorting.

Comment: Hi Duncan, thanks for the suggestion. When I went to implement it, it halfway worked. The issue is my "arr" array. Since it holds both the points/coords and lengths of the points to the origin, when I pass arr into the sort function, I get the same result. However, when I simplify arr to containing just length[i], I get an array of sorted length values, which is nice, but how can I relate those sorted lengths back to the original coordinates? That's where I am at right now.

Comment: You don't really need to do that stuff any more - you can just directly sort the `points` array that gets passed in and there's no need to store lengths in a separate array. The length only gets calculated during the sort process (implemented as a `getDistanceFromOrigin()` function).

Comment: To clarify, I'll expand my answer to include the full solution.

Comment: There's a magic number 2 in the `return` statement and the comment above it. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Sorting the whole array is wasteful, and may not even be possible. It is wasteful because the question didn't ask for a total ordering of all the elements, not even the `k` elements. Sorting using a comparison-based sort takes `O(n log(n))` time. More generally, if the input is a stream of numbers, storing all of them in the memory and sorting them may not even be possible.

I don't know much about JavaScript, but on general algorithmic turf, we can solve this problem faster using one of the following 2 methods:

1. Using a Max [Priority Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue): Create a max PQ with an ordering based on the distance from the origin. Keep inserting the elements in the max PQ, and whenever the size exceeds `k`, remove the top element (the maximum). In the end, the PQ would have the `k` smallest elements. Space complexity: `O(k)`, time complexity: `O(n log(k))` which for `k << n`, may be close to `O(n)`.
2. Using [Quick-select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect): Run quick-select k times on the input. This assumes the input fits in the memory (space `O(n)`), but runs in `O(nk)` time, which for `k << n`, may be close to `O(n)`.