# Java Algorithm Optimisation Question using a HashMap of Lists

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

If I had the following

```
postcodeToCompaniesList = new HashMap<String, List<Company>>();
```

After some processig the hashmap has many thousands of postcodes, and each postcode is mapped to a list with 1 or more `Company` objects.

Now I want to get the top 10 most popular postcodes and print out the number of companies at the postcode i.e. `"Postcode SW1A 0AA has 50 companies"`.

The approach I've taken, and I think this is naive, is to create a Record object to hold the postcode and the corrisponding number of companies at that postcode. I then create a `RecordList` object for managing a list of 10 `Record` objects which have the highest `count` value (see below).

The `RecordList.addRecord(Record record)` method adds `records` until 10 are added and then conditionally adds more only if the `count` value is higher than the lowest value currently in the list. Then it sorts the list and removes the lowest value thereby maintaing a count of 10 elements.

```
final class Record implements Comparable<Record> {
    public String postcode;
    public int count;

    public Record(String postcode, int count){
        this.postcode = postcode;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override 
    public int compareTo(Record r){
        return Integer.valueOf(this.count).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(r.count));
    }
}

final class RecordList{
    List<Record> top10 = new ArrayList<Record>();
    
    public void addRecord(Record record){
        if (this.top10.size() < 10){
            this.top10.add(record);
            Collections.sort(this.top10);
        } else if (record.count > this.top10.get(0).count){
            this.top10.add(record);
            Collections.sort(this.top10);
            this.top10.remove(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Next I use a simple loop to loop through all the keys (postcodes) and add them one at a time to the `RecordList` along with the `companyCount`.

```
RecordList recordList = new RecordList();
Set<String> postcodes = this.postcodeToCompaniesList.keySet();

for(String postcode : postcodes){
  int companyCount = this.postcodeToCompaniesList.get(postcode).size();
  recordList.addRecord(new Record(postcode, companyCount));
}

System.out.println(gson.toJson(recordList));
```

This works. However, I get the feeling that this is an very inefficent way to do this? Maybe Streams would work better??

What are the thoughts from the community? Is there a better, more elegent way to do this?

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar but do it as the company is added to its list.  At that point you know the new count; you then check that count against the min of top-10 and replace/insert as needed; if it's already in the top-10 then update its count and re-sort top-10.  One optimization is if new count is less than min of top-10 then no further processing needed.

Comment: How is _**most popular postcodes**_ defined? Postcode with the highest count of companies?

Comment: @Eritrean, from the O/P code, Yes: The most popular postcodes are those with the highest count of companies.

Comment: It strikes me as odd to see code that looks like a sort is being called each iteration in a loop. But, with each invocation of sort, no more than 10 items will be sorted, and the sort will actually be called no more than 10 times. Even so, you might want to consider a [priority queue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) or sorted collection.

Comment: If you want to do a web search, try "java find n largest elements in an array" or the same with "array" changed to "collection"   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272534/finding-the-first-n-largest-elements-in-an-array

Comment: I saw the following comment to a different question. It might apply here:  "Questions asking about improvements to correct, working code are better suited to CodeReview.SE"

Comment: Thanks Old Dog Programmer. I did try it out with a PriorityQueue, but it didn't make any significant differance to the execution time, although I do like the idea of using the priority queue OOTB functionlity.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if postcodeToCompaniesList had millions of entries, and you wanted to find the top thousand popular postcodes?  What would be the difference in execution time, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume List of Company  is a List of Strings to make things simpler. I think this should do it:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>(); // postcodes counter
postcodeToCompaniesList.forEach((postcode, company) -> counter.put(postcode, company.size()));

counter.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
    .limit(10)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a go. I'm still getting to grips with the Stream API

Comment: Hay Flavian, I don't understand the `.forEach(System.out::println);`. I understand the method passing to print them out, but how do I replace this in order to add each element into a List? Currently I have:
```
var recordList = new ArrayList<Record>();
....
.forEach(recordList.add(new Record(key, value)));
```
But that dosn't work. What does .ForEach pass in?

Comment: Sussed it:
.forEach(item -> recordList.add(new Record(item.getKey(), item.getValue())));

Comment: You don't have to print them, I think you can collect them like this:

`List<Entry<String, Integer>> result = counter.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .limit(10)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1):

You could stream over your entries sort them by the list size in reverse order, limit to n entries (in your case 10) and collect them in a LinkedHashMap:

```
private static Map<String, List<Company>> topN(Map<String, List<Company>> map, int n) {
    return map.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt((Map.Entry<String, List<Company>> e) -> e.getValue().size()).reversed())
              .limit(n)
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (x, y) -> y, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

and use it like below, for example to get the top 7 postcodes:

```
topN(postcodeToCompaniesList, 7)
        .forEach((k,v) -> System.out.printf("Postcode %s has %d companies.%n", k, v.size()));
```